# Is this a correct solution to show that the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ does not embed in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, extension-field

I know this is not a typical question and I will delete it later.

Here is a question together my answer. Please let me know if my answer is correct. The reason that I am posting this is that I believe my answer is correct but my professor refuses to accept that as a correct answer (with no explanation).

Question: Is it possible to embed the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

My Answer: No. Every element of $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$ so there is no copy of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ in $\mathbb{C}$ because $x$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You need to be more precise. Your argument shows that there is no embedding as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. Actually I think there is an embedding as rings if you assume axiom of choice.

Comment: Why do you intend to delete this question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought the moderators will close or delete it anyway. Otherwise I would not.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see, so my answer is not correct even if there is no embeding.

Comment: @Sara.T As rings, no, as $\Bbb{R}$-algebras, yes. So as you've written your question, no.

Answer (score 3):

Just to fill in the details of Tobias Kildetoft's comment. Not sure if they'll be useful to you, but I thought it was interesting.

Let's construct an embedding of $\Bbb{R}[x]$ into $\Bbb{C}$.

**Step 1** Observe that the transcendence degree of $\Bbb{C}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$ (though note that for our argument, it doesn't matter exactly what it is as long as it's infinite).

This follows from simple cardinality arguments. Any field algebraic over a field with an infinite cardinality has the same cardinality. If a field has cardinality $\alpha$ and we adjoin a cardinality $\beta$'s worth of indeterminates, the result will have cardinality $\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$.

**Step 2** Let $T$ be a transcendence basis for $\Bbb{C}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. Since $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and is algebraic over the subfield to $\Bbb{Q}(T)$, it is isomorphic to the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{Q}(T)$. Choose a proper subset $S$ of $T$ of the same cardinality as $T$. Then the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{Q}(S)$ in $\Bbb{C}$ is clearly isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$ as rings, since $\Bbb{Q}(S)\cong \Bbb{Q}(T)$, but it is necessarily a proper subset of $\Bbb{C}$, and doesn't contain any of the elements in $T\setminus S$.

**Step 3** By step 2, we have a (necessarily injective) ring homomorphism $\phi :\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ which isn't surjective. Let $t \in T\setminus S$. The ring homomorphism $\phi$ extends to an injective ring homomorphism
$\psi : \Bbb{C}[x]\to \Bbb{C}$ sending $x$ to $t$. Restricting to the obvious subset $\Bbb{R}[x]\subset \Bbb{C}[x]$ we have found an embedding of $\Bbb{R}[x]$ into $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: thanks. How about $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$ ?

Comment: @Sara.T Interesting question, but I'm not sure. You could ask a new question. Since you're still somewhat new to the site, I'll just advise you that if you do ask a new question, it's a good idea to explain that it's a follow up question to this one.